# how to upload image with reduced size

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp.net fileupload control for uploading  image but here i want to automatically re size to 250*200px.
please suggest me what to add in my code.
I am a novice to asp.net.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   string s =@"~\img\"+FileUpload1.FileName;
            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(s));


          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i also find this code useful for resizing

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing;

public partial class ImageUpload : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string ImageName = txtName.Text;
        if (FileUpLoad1.PostedFile != null && FileUpLoad1.PostedFile.FileName != null)
        {

            string strExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpLoad1.FileName);
            if ((strExtension.ToUpper() == ".JPG") | (strExtension.ToUpper() == ".GIF"))
            {
                // Resize Image Before Uploading to DataBase
                FileUpload fi = new FileUpload();
                fi = FileUpLoad1;

                System.Drawing.Image imageToBeResized = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream( fi.PostedFile.InputStream);
                int imageHeight = imageToBeResized.Height;
                int imageWidth = imageToBeResized.Width;
                int maxHeight = 120;
                int maxWidth = 160;
                imageHeight = (imageHeight * maxWidth) / imageWidth;
                imageWidth = maxWidth;

                if (imageHeight > maxHeight)
                {
                    imageWidth = (imageWidth * maxHeight) / imageHeight;
                    imageHeight = maxHeight;
                }

                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imageToBeResized, imageWidth, imageHeight);
                System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                stream.Position = 0;
                byte[] image = new byte[stream.Length + 1];
                stream.Read(image, 0, image.Length);

                // Create SQL Connection 
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Return_AuthorizationsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Images(ImageName,Image) VALUES (@ImageName,@Image)";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;

                SqlParameter ImageName1 = new SqlParameter("@ImageName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                ImageName1.Value = ImageName.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ImageName1);

                SqlParameter UploadedImage = new SqlParameter("@Image", SqlDbType.Image, image.Length);
                UploadedImage.Value = image;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(UploadedImage);
                con.Open();
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                if (result > 0)
                    lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded";
               GridView1.DataBind();
            }

            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get the image on the server you can resize it save it, and delete the original one.

a sample code only for resize

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/04/02/resizing-images-without-loss-of-quality.aspx

and here is a full project with source code to manipulate images, including resize.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/ASPImaging1.aspx